# form_with posts back using GET not POST?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to post back this form to my ***app_users_password_reset_path*** using ***form_with***, but for some reason, the method used is always GET as opposed to POST. In my controller, when I check **request.post?**, it's always false.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
# config/routes.rb

match '/app/users/password_reset', to: 'users#password_reset', as: :app_users_password_reset, via: [:get, :post]
```

The output from rails routes for the route in question is:

```
# > rails routes
app_users_password_reset GET|POST /app/users/password_reset(.:format) users#password_reset
```

Here is the markup for my form:

```
# password_reset.html.erb

 <div class='row'>
         <div class='body col-md-3'>

            <form>

                <%= form_with scope: :user,
                    method: :POST, 
                    url: app_users_password_reset_path,
                    local: true,
                    role: :form do |f| %>

                    <%= f.hidden_field :token, value: @password_reset_token %>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <%= f.label :user_password, "Password" %>
                        <%= f.password_field :password, value: @password, class: "form-control" %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Password confirmation" %>
                        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, value: @password_confirmation, class: "form-control"  %>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <%= f.submit "Reset password", id: "btn-reset-password", class: "btn btn-default" %>
                    </div>
                <% end %>

            </form>

        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Keep close tabs on `log/development.log` to see what's going on here and verify that the source emitted shows `method="POST"` in the `<form>` tag.

Comment: @tadman, no, it's definitely GET: "Started GET "/app/users/password_reset?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=w6DzO3r5vFO25H1IyOk%2B8ZQN3nBrj42VTco%2BEIpGWcQASW6FYF0Jj%2B9E0byJxWsPvDcBhMAHqHw9bUW7I1GzdQ%3D%3D&user%5Btoken%5D=1&user%5Bpassword%5D=[FILTERED]&user%5Bpassword_confirmation%5D=[FILTERED]&commit=Reset+password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-17 15:32:59 -0500"

Comment: That's why it's necessary to check the HTML source as well to be sure the form is configured correctly. I think `form_with` is `POST` by default, so specifying `method` should not be necessary.

Comment: The form_with code is wrapped inside another html form tag, this may be causing the issue. Try removing the <form> and </form> tag.

Comment: @NarenSisodiya good grief, how could I miss that. That was it :)

Comment: Good to know, it worked. Adding my comment as answer please do accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form_with code is wrapped inside another html form tag, this may be causing the issue. Try removing the  and  tag.